Issue with SSL for Confluence Java back-end REST API
I have problems to get uploaded files to work with Confluence API's REST Client on Java EE back-end for OpenAI Speech-to-Text feature that needs correct configuration in SSL and not only https on Web-browser.
Problem? I have client-side React 18 code that successfully upload oga file via Confluence REAT Client to my Confluence page attachment but in case this java code try to download with via server-side Java REST Client for purpose to send it for transcript of OpenAI to generate this audio file to text throws to SSL error. So it not help if SSL is configured to Apache 2. It is also needed to correctly configured to Tomcat of my Atlassian Confluence instance
Here is what I try to do without success.
./conf/server.xml in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
<Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
               maxThreads="48" maxPostSize="16777216" minSpareThreads="10"
               enableLookups="false" acceptCount="100" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               scheme="https" secure="true" proxyName="www.mydomain.com" proxyPort="443"
               disableUploadTimeout="true" 
               keystoreFile="conf/keystore.jks"
               keystorePass="mypassowrd"
    />

<SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/keystore.jks"
                 certificateKeystorePassword="mypassword"
         certificateKeyAlias="tomcat"
                 type="RSA" />
</SSLHostConfig>

mod_proxy setting on virtualhost SSL file
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8090/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8090/

./bin/setenv.sh
# Set TSL trust zone
CATALINA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/atlassian/confluence/conf/keystore.jks ${CATALINA_OPTS}"
CATALINA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypassword ${CATALINA_OPTS}"

Export certificate
keytool -export -alias tomcat -file tomcat.crt -keystore conf/keystore.jks

Import certificate
keytool -import -alias tomcat -file tomcat.crt -keystore conf/truststore.jks

Also I have Let's Encrypt Wildcard CA on my VPS.
Content of /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com
cert.pem
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
keystore.p12
privkey.pem
README


I have problems what problems?

I have client-side React 18 code that successfully upload oga file via Confluence REAT Client to my Confluence page attachment but in case this java code try to download with via server-side Java REST Client for purpose to send it for transcript of OpenAI to generate this audio file to text throws to SSL error. So it not help if SSL is configured to Apache 2. It is also needed to correctly configured to Tomcat of my Atlassian Confluence instance.

So my SSL settings on Tomcat side is wrong.
